# Send in multiple topic kafka sink with flink

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-flink, kafka-producer-api, flink-streaming

I have a data stream like :

```
DataStream[myTuple(topic, value)]
```

And I wanted to send a specific value in the associated topic.

So I try to do somthing like that :

```
new FlinkKafkaProducer010[myTuple](
  "default_topic",
  new KeyedSerializationSchema[myTuple](){
    override def getTargetTopic(element: myTuple): String = element.topic
    override def serializeKey(element: myTuple): Array[Byte] = null
    override def serializeValue(element: myTuple): Array[Byte] = new SimpleStringSchema().serialize(element.value)
  },
  properties)
```

but it doesn't work and I have this warning:

```
WARN  org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducerBase  - Overwriting the 'key.serializer' is not recommended
WARN  org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducerBase  - Overwriting the 'value.serializer' is not recommended
```

I have no idea how to do it, by another way.
thx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably set `key.serializer` and `value.serializer` in your properties. You should not do this, cause this way you overwrite serializers (`ByteArraySerializer`s) used internally by Flink. Remove those properties and your code should work.

Comment: In properties I only add `bootstrap.servers`

Comment: Please check it thoroughly, cause the warning message states exactly that you do...

Comment: I fix my issue : the issue was I try to open a kafka connection for each entry